# If I have two substring_index, which one gets executed first?

Tags: mysql, database, substring

If I have two substring_index, which one get executed first? the internal one `substring_index(`mycol`,'/',3)`, or the external one ?

```
substring_index(substring_index(`mycol`,'/',3),'://',-1)
```

Examples of sting I want to treat:

```
https://www.yahoo.com/
http://google.com/en/
```

I want to get:

```
www.yahoo.com
google.com
```

1) Which `substring_index` get executed first? This important to know to construct the second `substring_index` according to the output of what executed first.

2) Is my `substring_index` statement correct?

Comment: for each nested  function  is always exectued  the  inner  one  .. and recorsively  the next outer  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asu you can easy check

```
select substring_index(substring_index('https://www.yahoo.com/','/',3),'://',-1);
```

www.yahoo.com

```
select substring_index(substring_index('http://google.com/en/','/',3),'://',-1);
```

google.com

for each nested function is always exectued the inner one .. and recorsively the next outer

Answer (score 0):

The outer `substring_index()` cannot be executed unless there exists a value on which to operate on. 
In this case the value to operate on is:

```
substring_index(`mycol`,'/',3)
```

So the nested `substring_index()` is executed 1st and provides the value on which the outer `substring_index()` operates on.
This is the way that all programming languages including SQL evaluate expressions.
As for the 2nd question: yes the statement is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative to using `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, if you are using MySQL 8+ you could use a regex replacement function:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE('http://google.com/en/', 'https?://([^/]+)', '$1') AS url
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

1. the statement in parentheses always have higher priority.
2. inner substring index just trims the ‘/‘ char at the end. (‘https://www.yahoo.com’). outer substring index trims ‘https://‘. (‘www.yahoo.com’). Your statement is just fine.

You can find different usages or detailed info [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).